# Java based websocket client for Spring based websocket server

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I have this websocket server developed using Spring Boot. The server is working fine with a js based client.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat");
    }

}
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public OutputMessage send(final Message message) throws Exception {

        final String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
        return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText(), time);
    }

}
```

This is the server side. Now, for the client, I have created a @ClientEndpoint and when I connect to the URI "ws://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-java/chat", I am able to establish a connection and I can see that the @OnOpen callback of @ClientEndpoint is triggered.

However, it seems that the userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message) does not have any effect. I don't see the response from the server.

I can see the js client is:

1. Connecting to the server var socket = new SockJS('/spring-mvc-java/chat')
2. Subscribing stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages',...
3. Send the message stompClient.send("/app/chat",...

I am able to achieve the first step. How to achieve the 2nd and the 3rd step in a Java based client?

Thanks

Comment: when you say java based client, are you using any web socket library and stomp library?

Comment: No. No stomp, no sockjs. I am actually trying to follow this thing http://www.programmingforliving.com/2013/08/jsr-356-java-api-for-websocket-client-api.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a websocketclient and websocketstompclient

```
WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
```

You have to custom handler from `StompSessionHandler` for

```
getPayloadType
handleFrame
afterConnected
handleException
handleTransportError
```

methods

```
StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new CustomStompSessionHandler();
```

You can connect your sockets like this. You can accomplish sending and receiving messages

```
StompSession stompSession=stompClient.connect("ws://localhost:8080/chat",sessionHandler).get();
```

This two trigger your websocket `topic/messages` give you messages through the sockets

`/app/chat` sending `Message` to sockets

```
stompSession.subscribe("/topic/messages", sessionHandler);
stompSession.send("/app/chat", new Message("Hi", "user"));
```

do you want like this?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Throwing pieces of code will not help anything. Try to construct a minimal piece of code with some references. I can't get how the incomming messages will be handled. Where are the callback functions? Need to extend some class ? need to override any method? Where do I put any of these lost codes? A Service? A controller?